# Matplotlib not displaying 2D graphs after XGBoosting

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, random-forest, xgboost

I am trying to use matplotlib library in Google Colab. I am running the following code, while it is not throwing any error and giving an output, it is not displaying the graph.

The code is

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(alpha, cv_auc_array,c='g')
for i, txt in enumerate(np.round(cv_auc_array,3)):
    ax.annotate((alpha[i],np.round(txt,3)), (alpha[i],cv_auc_array[i]))
plt.grid()
plt.title("Cross Validation Error for each alpha")
plt.xlabel("Alpha i's")
plt.ylabel("Error measure")
plt.show()
```

and this is the output

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f1aba32d3f0>]Text(10, 0.9153004470823272, '(10, 0.915)')Text(50, 0.9195639735047957, '(50, 0.92)')Text(100, 0.9164096670642887, '(100, 0.916)')Text(500, 0.9062836402781415, '(500, 0.906)')Text(1000, 0.9019401045454987, '(1000, 0.902)')Text(2000, 0.9004162908653612, '(2000, 0.9)')Text(0.5, 1.0, 'Cross Validation Error for each alpha')Text(0.5, 0, "Alpha i's")Text(0, 0.5, 'Error measure')
```

I would really appreciate the help with this. I am trying to display the graph after using XGBoost library. I cannot use VSCode as XGBoost does not support GPU on Apple Silicon.

Thanks!

Update

the data in cv_auc_array is

```
[0.9153004470823272,
 0.9195639735047957,
 0.9164096670642887,
 0.9062836402781415,
 0.9019401045454987,
 0.9004162908653612]
```

and XGBoost code is as  follows

```
alpha=[10,50,100,500,1000,2000]
cv_auc_array=[]
for i in alpha:
    x_cfl=x_cfl=XGBClassifier(n_estimators=i, tree_method="gpu_hist")
    x_cfl.fit(X_train,y_train)
    sig_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(x_cfl, method="sigmoid")
    sig_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predict_y = sig_clf.predict_proba(X_cv)
    cv_auc_array.append(roc_auc_score(y_cv, predict_y[:,1]))
    
for i in range(len(cv_auc_array)):
    print ('AUC for number of estimators = ',alpha[i],'is',cv_auc_array[i])

best_alpha = np.argmax(cv_auc_array)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Would you mind providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's possible to investigate what's going on?

Comment: @SimonDavid I hope the edit helps

Comment: thanks for the edits! I was able to generate the graph using the code above; however, what's missing is a reproducible example featuring your `XGB` model since it's the suspect behind your problem - in the Minimal, Reproducible Example it should be possible to reproduce the error that is bugging you

Comment: @SimonDavid I have edited the post with the XGBoost model as well. I think this example might work